# Shapeless type inference for HList does not work

Tags: scala, functional-programming, generic-programming, shapeless, type-level-computation

I'm trying to implement generic function for taking the first element:

```
import shapeless.ops.hlist.IsHCons
import shapeless.{Generic, HList}

object App {

  def main(args : Array[String]) {
    val a: Int = getFirst((1, 2, 3))
    val b: String = getFirst(("a", "b", 10, 45, "aaa"))
  }

  def getFirst[A, Head, Repr <: HList, Tail <: HList](input: A)
                                                     (implicit hcons: IsHCons.Aux[Repr, Head, Tail],
                                                      gen: Generic.Aux[A, Repr]): Head = gen.to(input).head
}
```

The problem is the compiler cannot correctly infer `Repr` and `Tail` and sets them to `Nothing`. Here is it:

```
Error:(9, 26) could not find implicit value for parameter gen: shapeless.Generic.Aux[(Int, Int, Int),Repr]
    val a: Int = getFirst((1, 2, 3))
Error:(9, 26) not enough arguments for method getFirst: (implicit hcons: shapeless.ops.hlist.IsHCons.Aux[Nothing :: Nothing,Head,Tail], implicit gen: shapeless.Generic.Aux[(Int, Int, Int),Nothing :: Nothing])Head.
Unspecified value parameter gen.
    val a: Int = getFirst((1, 2, 3))
Error:(10, 29) could not find implicit value for parameter gen: shapeless.Generic.Aux[(String, String, Int),Repr]
    val b: String = getFirst(("a", "b", 10))
Error:(10, 29) not enough arguments for method getFirst: (implicit hcons: shapeless.ops.hlist.IsHCons.Aux[Nothing :: Nothing,Head,Tail], implicit gen: shapeless.Generic.Aux[(String, String, Int),Nothing :: Nothing])Head.
Unspecified value parameter gen.
    val b: String = getFirst(("a", "b", 10))
```

What would be a solution to fix it? The following works fine for sure:

```
val a: Int = getFirst[(Int, Int, Int), Int, Int :: Int :: Int :: HNil, Int :: Int :: HNil]((1, 2, 3))
```

But this is extremely cumbersome and ugly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to swap implicit parameter order - `Generic` first, `IsHCons` second.

```scala
  def getFirst[A, Head, Repr <: HList, Tail <: HList](input: A)
                                                     (implicit gen: Generic.Aux[A, Repr], hcons: IsHCons.Aux[Repr, Head, Tail]
                                                      ): Head = gen.to(input).head
```

[(scastie)](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/me9We1gSSo6TQB1lyTE2ew)

I don't know how exactly this works, but I've seen that inferring type parameters via resolving implicits works left to right.

So, with your signature, Scala first looks for `IsHCons.Aux[Repr, Head, Tail]`, but it doesn't know much about `Repr` at this point, just that it is an HList. It finds *some* instance - probably for something like `Nothing :: HList`, and then tries to look for `Generic.Aux[A, Nothing :: HList]` (`A` is inferred from `input`), which fails since that is not a valid `Generic` for `A`.